# aws rds start-export-task returns internal error

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am trying to use "start-export-task" to export an Aurora RDS snapshot to an S3 folder. I am able to successfully perform this using the dashboard but if I try to do it via CLI or Lambda API I get a "internal error - try again later".

The command I used is (I changed my account info and key to xxx's) -

```
aws rds start-export-task \
--region us-east-2 \
--export-task-identifier ernie-export \
--source-arn arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxx:cluster-snapshot:export-test-1 \
--s3-bucket-name dev-rds-backups \
--iam-role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/test-export-rds-to-s3-role \
--kms-key-id xxxxxxx-xxxx-4313-baxx-7axxxxfxxxx
```

The error I get:

> An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the StartExportTask operation (reached max retries: 4): An internal error has occurred. Please try your query again at a later time.